# Rails 4 + react-rails gem: Could not find generator 'react:install'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs, bundler, react-rails

I am trying to follow [this Airpair tutorial](https://www.airpair.com/reactjs/posts/reactjs-a-guide-for-rails-developers) by Fernando Villalobos, to play around with Rails and React through the `react-rails` gem.

I created a brand new Rails 4 app and I am now trying to install `react-rails`.

**This is my Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.2'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'react-rails', '~> 1.4.0'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end
```

I already ran both `bundle install` and `bundle update` (just in case).

**But, whenever I try to run `rails g react:install` [as recommended here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails#installation), I keep getting the following error:**

```
Could not find generator 'react:install'. Maybe you meant 'test_unit:job' or 'test_unit:model' or 'generator'
Run `rails generate --help` for more options.
```

**Any idea of what's wrong here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I just tried it again in a new rails project - without running bundle install first - and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Try running `spring stop`. You might have attached to an old process.

Comment: Worked for me after stoping spring process. Thx!!